Way to run the script faster
I have a mathematica code, which is running fine, but it takes long time to evaluate.I have already modified the code with compilation and vectorization as you can see from my code.
May be its a stupid idea to ask for checking the code when there is no error, but I want to evaluate it in less time without changing any parameter like "taud" and "Selectedangle". So any idea/suggestion will be really helpful. Thanks in advance! Following is my updated code:
I also have removed the neumeric integration and replaced by integrated results which makes the script little bit faster.
Hx = 1 /2 KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[1], IdentityMatrix[2]]; Hy = 
 1 /2 KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[2], IdentityMatrix[2]]; Hz = 
 1 /2 KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[3], IdentityMatrix[2]];
Cx = 1 /2 KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[2], PauliMatrix[1]]; Cy = 
 1 /2 KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[2], PauliMatrix[2]]; Cz = 
 1 /2 KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[2], PauliMatrix[3]];
\[Omega]D = 2 \[Pi] 8; \[Omega]CS = 2 \[Pi] 2; \[Omega]r = 
 2 \[Pi] 10; \[Omega]H = 2 \[Pi] 4; \[Omega]C = 
 2 \[Pi] 1; \[Tau]r = (2 \[Pi])/\[Omega]r; \[Tau]contact = 0.1751; \
Selectedangle = 
 Table[{RandomReal[] \[Pi], RandomReal[] 2 \[Pi]}, {100}]; \[Tau]d = 
 Range[0, 2, 0.05]; time = Table[i, {i, 0, 3, 0.003}];
\[Omega]Dt[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] = \[Omega]D (\[Sqrt]2 Sin[
       2 \[Beta]] Cos[\[Omega]r t + \[Gamma]] - (Sin[\[Beta]])^2 Cos[
       2 \[Omega]r t + 2 \[Gamma]]);
\[Omega]CSt[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] = \[Omega]CS (-\[Sqrt]2 Sin[
       2 \[Beta]] Cos[\[Omega]r t + \[Gamma]] + (Sin[\[Beta]])^2 Cos[
       2 \[Omega]r t + 2 \[Gamma]]);
\[Rho]0 = Hz + Cz; U0 = 
 MatrixExp[-I Integrate[Hy, {t, 0, \[Pi]/2}]]; \[Rho]1 = 
 U0.\[Rho]0.U0\[ConjugateTranspose];
Dipol1[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] = \[Omega]D /\[Omega]r (-Cos[
        2 \[Gamma] + \[Tau]contact \[Omega]r] Sin[\[Beta]]^2 Sin[\
\[Tau]contact \[Omega]r] + 
     Sqrt[2] Sin[
       2 \[Beta]] (-Sin[\[Gamma]] + 
        Sin[\[Gamma] + \[Tau]contact \[Omega]r]));
U1[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] := MatrixExp[-I*integral1[\[Beta], \[Gamma]]];
\[Rho]2[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] := 
  Dot[U1[\[Beta], \[Gamma]], \[Rho]1, 
   U1[\[Beta], \[Gamma]]\[ConjugateTranspose]];
Dipol2[t_, \[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] = 
  Integrate[\[Omega]Dt[\[Beta], \[Gamma]], t];
delayintegral[t_, \[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] := 
  Dipol2[\[Beta], \[Gamma], t] (2 Hz.Cz);
U2[t_, \[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] := 
  MatrixExp[-I*delayintegral[t, \[Beta], \[Gamma]]];
\[Rho]3[t_, \[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] := 
  Dot[U2[t, \[Beta], \[Gamma]], \[Rho]2[\[Beta], \[Gamma]], 
   U2[t, \[Beta], \[Gamma]]\[ConjugateTranspose]];
Dipol1t[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] = \[Omega]D /\[Omega]r (2 Sqrt[2]
       Cos[\[Gamma] + (\[Tau]r \[Omega]r)/4] Sin[
       2 \[Beta]] Sin[(\[Tau]r \[Omega]r)/4] - 
     Cos[2 \[Gamma] + (\[Tau]r \[Omega]r)/
        2] Sin[\[Beta]]^2 Sin[(\[Tau]r \[Omega]r)/2]);
Dipol2t[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] = \[Omega]D /\[Omega]r (2 Sqrt[2]
       Cos[\[Gamma] + (3 \[Tau]r \[Omega]r)/4] Sin[
       2 \[Beta]] Sin[(\[Tau]r \[Omega]r)/4] - 
     Cos[2 \[Gamma] + (3 \[Tau]r \[Omega]r)/
        2] Sin[\[Beta]]^2 Sin[(\[Tau]r \[Omega]r)/2]);
U901 = MatrixExp[-I Integrate[Cx, {t, 0, \[Pi]/2}]];
Ucycle1[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] := 
  MatrixExp[-I (Dipol1t[\[Beta], \[Gamma]] (2 Hz.Cz))];
Ucycle2 = MatrixExp[-I Integrate[Cx, {t, 0, \[Pi]}]];
Ucycle3[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] := 
  MatrixExp[-I (Dipol2t[\[Beta], \[Gamma]] (2 Hz.Cz))];
U902 = MatrixExp[-I Integrate[Cx, {t, 0, \[Pi]/2}]];
Ucycle[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] := 
  U902.MatrixPower[(Ucycle3[\[Beta], \
\[Gamma]].Ucycle2.Ucycle1[\[Beta], \[Gamma]]), 10].U901;
\[Rho]0delay[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] := 
 Dot[Ucycle[\[Beta], \[Gamma]], \[Rho]2[\[Beta], \[Gamma]], 
  Ucycle[\[Beta], \[Gamma]]\[ConjugateTranspose]];(*With no Delay*)\
\[Rho]delay[tdelay_, \[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] := 
 Dot[Ucycle[\[Beta], \[Gamma]], \[Rho]3[tdelay, \[Beta], \[Gamma]], 
  Ucycle[\[Beta], \[Gamma]]\[ConjugateTranspose]];
CS[t_, \[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] = \[Omega]CS/\[Omega]r Sin[\[Beta]] (-2 \
Sqrt[2] Cos[\[Beta]] + 
     Cos[\[Gamma] + t \[Omega]r] Sin[\[Beta]]) Sin[\[Gamma] + 
     t \[Omega]r];
\[CapitalDelta]CS[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] = 
  Re@CS[time, \[Beta], \[Gamma]] - 
   First@Re@CS[time, \[Beta], \[Gamma]];
integral2[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] := 
  TensorProduct[\[CapitalDelta]CS[\[Beta], \[Gamma]], (Cz)];
Ud[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] := 
  MatrixExp[-I*#] & /@ integral2[\[Beta], \[Gamma]];
compiled\[Rho]sample = 
  Compile[{{tdelay, _Real, 2}, {\[Beta], _Real, 1}, {\[Gamma], _Real, 
     1}}, Block[{ud, rhoSample, rhoDcList}, ud = Ud[\[Beta], \[Gamma]];
    rhoSample = \[Rho]delay[tdelay, \[Beta], \[Gamma]];
    rhoDcList = 
     Map[Dot[ud[[#]], rhoSample, ConjugateTranspose[ud[[#]]]] &, 
      Range@Length[ud]];
    rhoDcList], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   Parallelization -> True, 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];
compiledintmed = 
  Compile[{{tdelay, _Real, 2}, {\[Beta], _Real, 1}, {\[Gamma], _Real, 
     1}}, Block[{rhoDcList, result}, 
    rhoDcList = compiled\[Rho]sample[tdelay, \[Beta], \[Gamma]];
    result = 
     Map[Tr[(Cx - I Cy)\[ConjugateTranspose].rhoDcList[[#]]] &, 
      Range@Length[rhoDcList]];
    result], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True,
    CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];
output = Table[
    Total[Map[compiledintmed[i, #[[1]], #[[2]]] &, 
      Selectedangle]], {i, \[Tau]d[[1]], \[Tau]d[[
      Length@\[Tau]d]], \[Tau]d[[2]] - \[Tau]d[[
       1]]}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Off[CompiledFunction::cfta]


Have you tried using, e.g., EchoTiming to narrow down which parts of the code are slowest?

Ooooh, I did not even know that EchoTiming existed. How convenient!

@SjoerdSmit I could not use EchoTiming as I am using Mathematica 12.0. However I checked with AbsoluteTiming in each line that when I "Map" the values (Selectedangle and taud) to get the "output" it takes most of the time. I even tried with "For" and "Do" loop instead of "Map", but that did not improve the compuation time.

Look at CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint[compiled\[Rho]sample] and CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint[compiledintmed]. With these many occurrences of MainEvaluate I would not be surprised if this takes longer than evaluating this without Compile.

Also not that things line Integrate or MatrixExp do not compile. However, many of the expressions here seem to be evaluatable at compile time. So delayed definitions are diametral to performance. You should push as many calculations as possible to compile time.

{tdealy, _Real, 1} is declared to be a vector, but you pass-in the scalar i. And {\[Beta], _Real, 3} are supposed to be three-dimensional arrays, but you pass - in scalars #[[1]] #[[2]] ,  too . Moreover, i is also not defined in the compiledintmed.  Nothing of that makes any sense .

@HenrikSchumacher I have modified as {tdealy, _Real, 2},{[Beta], _Real, 1}, {[Gamma], _Real, 1} and additionally removed “i" in both compiled[Rho]sample and compiledintmed as I am now using Map instead of Table in both compilefunctions, but that does not improve computing time at all. Additionally when I compute without compiling it is 6 times slower.

Good. Then maybe you should update your code here, too.
